# Android camera images frozen in API > 14 after dialog dismiss

Tags: android, dialog, camera, freeze, zbar

I am developing an Android app which is basically a QR reader. The reason why I'm developing my own reader is that although my app also reads standard QR codes, when it reads codes that point to my own website I make a change in the content before accessing it. I make that change as I want to redirect the user to that content in his/her own language.

Anyways, during the development I have been testing the app with my Android phone, which is a 2.3.4 Gingerbread. Once I accomplished the reading of the codes I started testing the app with an Android 4.2 and an Android 4.3 too, which a friend lent me as a favour. However, it didn't completely work... I should say that in order to provide more control and security to the user (see [attaging](http://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/papers/attack/attaging.pdf)) I show a dialog when a QR code that contains a URL has been read, so that the user can accept or reject to access that address.

The Android 4.x phone starts the camera and reads the code with no problem but if the user rejects to access the address shown in the dialog the images shown in the app will be frozen and will not change. However, the camera does work because if you try to focus another QR code (even if you cannot see it in the screen) it will show the dialog, showing the code it has just read. Furthermore, when the user accepts to access the address in a web browser and then returns to the app the camera gets loaded correctly. As I said, this only happens when I test the app with an Android 4.x device, as it works fine in my 2.3.4 Android.

In order to make the development easier I've used the Zbar bar code reader library for reading the QR codes. I attach snippets of my code below:

**MainActivity**(The activity that reads the codes and displays the dialog)

```
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreviewmPreview;
private Handler autoFocusHandler;
private FrameLayout preview;

ImageScanner scanner;

private boolean previewing = true;
private boolean initialisation = true;

// ...    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set the layout for the Activity
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Check whether is the first execution. If it is initialise all necessary components
    if (initialisation) {
        autoFocusHandler = new Handler();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        /* Instance barcode scanner */
        scanner = new ImageScanner();
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(mCamera, previewCb,
                autoFocusCB);
        preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
        // Starting from this point, we will not execute the initialisation code any more
        initialisation= false;
    } else {
        rerunCamera();
    }
}

public void rerunCamera() {
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    mPreview = new KameraAurrebista(this, mCamera, previewCb,
            autoFocusCB);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
}

public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "@+string/badInstance" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return c;
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        previewing = false;
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

public void onCodeRead(String url) {
    previewing = false;
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    // ...
    releaseCamera();
    AlertDialog.Builder showDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                this);

                        // Button for when the user accepts to access the url
                        showDialog.setPositiveButton(
                                R.string.acceptURL,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                });

                        // Button for when the user rejects to access the url
                        showDialog.setNegativeButton(
                                R.string.rejectURL,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        // Close dialog and manually call onResume so that the camera is re-run
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                        onResume();
                                    }
                                });
                        showDialog.create();
                        showDialog.setTitle(R.string.dialogTitle);
                        String dialogText= getResources().getString(
                                R.string.dialogText);
                        showDialog.setMessage(dialogText+ " " + url);
                        showDialog.show();
}
```

**R.layout.main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>    

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scanText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.31"
            android:background="#A0A0A0"
            android:text="@+string/scanning"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>`
```

**CameraPreview**

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private PreviewCallback previewCallback;
private AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback;

public CameraPreview (Camera camera,
                     PreviewCallback previewCb,
                     AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCb) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    previewCallback = previewCb;
    autoFocusCallback = autoFocusCb;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);

    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("DBG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Empty function
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    /*
     * If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
     * Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
     */
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
      // preview surface does not exist
      return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
      // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("DBG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}